# Filtered Index expression does not work on Bit

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I want a bool constraint on a certain value for column IsDefaultLanguage:

```
Id...ISO639_ISO3166...ApplicationId...IsDefaultLanguage
1....de-de............1...............1
2....fr-fr............1...............1
```

The second datarow insertion should result in a unique error because IsDefaultLanguage should only be allowed ONE for True (1) for an application.
Also should a language be available only ONE for an application.

The Filter index does not work on my side (Sql Server 2014)

What do I wrong?

**TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Languages](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ISO639_ISO3166] [char](5) NOT NULL,
    [ApplicationId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsDefaultLanguage] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Languages] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Languages]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Languages_dbo.Applications_ApplicationId] FOREIGN KEY([ApplicationId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Applications] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Languages] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Languages_dbo.Applications_ApplicationId]
GO
```

**INDEX**

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_IsoCodeApplicationId] ON [dbo].[Languages]
(
    [ISO639_ISO3166] ASC,
    [ApplicationId] ASC,
    [IsDefaultLanguage] ASC
)
WHERE ([IsDefaultLanguage]=(1))
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

Comment: But the values for `ISO639_ISO3166` are different in your 2 rows.. If you don't care about that, why do you have that column defined as part of your unique index?

Comment: You cannot do what you want with an index.   You can use a trigger or a check constraint with a UDF.

Comment: You have a sample with UDF ?

Comment: *"The second datarow insertion should result in a unique error because IsDefaultLanguage should only be allowed ONE for True (1) for an application. Also should a language be available only ONE for an application.*": These 2 sentences are difficult to understand.  Can you try to reword it please?

Comment: http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/using-udf-check-constraint-validate-column

Comment: actually, as I learn more about filtered indexes, I think your index will work if you remove  [ISO639_ISO3166] as an indexed column.

Comment: The link is 15 years old? still valid?

Comment: Yes, still valid.   UDF and Check Constraint work the same as it worked in SQL 2000.

Comment: @TabAlleman " I think your index will work..." that is true! But then I can have the same isocode for an applicationId and this must be forbidden. The isocode must be unique for an ApplictionId which is foreignkey.

Comment: You can enforce that with a separate, unfiltered, unique index (or constraint) on ApplicationID / IsoCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The second datarow insertion should result in a unique error because IsDefaultLanguage should only be allowed ONE for True (1) for an application. Also should a language be available only ONE for an application.

The above is not very clear to me.  Here is what I think you are trying to say:

- `IsDefaultLanguage` can only have the value `1` once per `ApplicationId`.
- The value for `ISO639_ISO3166` must be unique per `ApplicationId`

If that's the case, split your index in 2 separate indexes to take care of your 2 different requirements:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_IsoCodeApplicationId] ON [dbo].[Languages]
(
    [ISO639_ISO3166] ASC,
    [ApplicationId] ASC
)

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_DefaultLanguageApplicationId] ON [dbo].[Languages]
(
    [IsDefaultLanguage] ASC,
    [ApplicationId] ASC,
)
WHERE ([IsDefaultLanguage]=(1))
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Now I need to make it work for Entity Framework Code First somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Your index is defined incorrectly for what you're trying to do. Let's look at it another way. You'd expect that the following query would return 0 rows:

```
select [ApplicationID], count(*)
from [dbo].[Languages]
where [IsDefaultLanguage] = 1
group by [ApplicationID]
having count(*) > 1
```

That is, per ApplicationID, there is only one row with a value of IsDefaultLanguage = 1. So, your index should be:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_IsoCodeApplicationId] 
ON [dbo].[Languages]
(
    [ApplicationId] ASC
)
WHERE ([IsDefaultLanguage]=(1))
```

Completing the analogy with the query, there will (read: can) only ever be one row per ApplicationID in the index (because it's a unique index).